# Is there a difference between extending Object vs not extending at all in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I found out that I can extend Object like this:

```
class MyObject extends Object {}
```

Is there any difference with this and not extending at all, like this:

```
class MyObject {}
```

The reason I ask this is because I have the following mixin:

```
const MapMixin = (Base = Object) => class extends Base {
  static from(array) {
    return new this(Object.assign(...array.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))));
  }

  map(...args) {
    return this.constructor.from(this.entries().map(...args));
  }

  entries() {
    return Object.entries(this);
  }
};
```

This mixin could be used like this:

```
class MyObject extends MapMixin(MyBaseClass) {}
```

But if there is no base class, I now have specified that it then extends `Object` as default:

```
class MyObject extends MapMixin() {}
```

So I'm wondering, if this practically works the same as not extending anything at all.

Comment: Aren't all Object's prototypes `Object` by default? (unless you use `Object.create(null)`) --- Update... it seems not.

Comment: On the other hand, why are you extending at all?

Comment: @evolutionxbox After experimenting a bit, there seems to be some differences. Try logging `(class extends Object{}).freeze` vs `(class {}).freeze`.

Comment: Why extend? Why bother with classical inheritance at all?

Comment: If I wanted to use the Object freeze method? `Object.freeze(MyObject)`.

Comment: Yes, if you extend a class, all static methods of the base class are copied onto the child class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's clear from the other answers here, but the difference is in the **static** inheritance.

Prior to the `class` keyword, inheritance in JavaScript has been very focused on instance inheritance.  No one (that I've seen) cared to go through the trouble of having one class/constructor inherit static members from the super class/constructor.  Not to mention the only way to do this was through the non-standard `__proto__` property.

So when we look at a class extending another class today, we think about how inheritance works between instances of that class.  For instances, extending `Object`, or nothing at all, is the same because instances will inherently inherit from `Object` as a base.

```
class A {}
class B extends Object {}

let a = new A()
let b = new B()

// a.__proto__.__proto__ === b.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

But it may not be clear, or well understood that the `extends` keyword is doing more than just setting up inheritance for instances. It also sets up inheritance between the class constructors.  So for `B` above, the use of `extends` also means a `Object.setPrototypeOf(B, Object)` getting called in the background for B.  So, for example:

```
class A {} // A constructor inherits nothing (is a basic Function type)
class B extends Object {} // B inherits from Object

// A.setPrototypeOf === undefined
// B.setPrototypeOf === Object.setPrototypeOf
```

`B`, extending `Object`, inherits all the static methods from `Object`, whereas `A` not extending anything, doesn't.

The difference is between `B.prototype` (or `B.prototype.__proto__`) - what instances inherit from, and `B.__proto__` - what the class constructor inherits from.  Extending `Object` or not does not affect the `prototype` or what the instances inherit from, but it does affect the class's `__proto__`, or static inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a subtle difference.

If you declare classes A, B and create instances like this:

```
class A {}
class B extends Object {}

let a = new A()
let b = new B()
```

`A` is a **base class**, and `B` is a **derived class**.

As a result, `a` is allocated directly from `A` but `b` is allocated from `Object`.
So you can find their prototypes:

```
console.log(A.__proto__) // [Function]          (Function.prototype)
console.log(B.__proto__) // [Function: Object]  (Object)
```

via http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#the-extends-clause.

Comment: Interestingly, `a`/`b`'s prototype chain length is the same.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm wondering, why does `let b = new B({prop: 'value'})` not have the property `prop` set to value, but `let obj = new Object({prop: 'value'})` does have the property `prop` set. Isn't that strange as `B` inherits the constructor from `Object`?

Comment: Ach, that doesn't come out right in a comment box. Making actual response just for formatting

Comment: @Kasper: It seems, from the Chrome console, that `new (class extends Object{})({ prop: value })` is equivalent to `new (class prop extends Object{})()`

Comment: On further investigation, it seems that Chrome just names an instance of any anonymous class as the first key of any object passed in to its constructor

Answer (score 1):

As [Shu Ding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2424786/shu-ding) said, the prototype chain differs

To be more explicit:

```
const getNProtos = (n, { __proto__:p }={}, protos=[]) => n && p ? getNProtos(n-1, p, [ ...protos, p ]) : [ ...protos, p ]

[ 
  class extends Object{}, 
  class extends (class {}){}, 
  class {} 
].map(obj => getNProtos(3, obj)
  .forEach(x => x.forEach(y => console.log(y)) || console.log('\n'))
)

ƒ Object() { [native code] }
ƒ () { [native code] }
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
null


class {}
ƒ () { [native code] }
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
null


ƒ () { [native code] }
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
null
```

The prototype chains are almost identical, with the derived class simply having an extra one (the Object constructor) atop the chain. Extending with Object looks similar to extending with a plain `class {}`, except of course that Object has its own methods available.